# How can I check if folders are empty?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (textBoxRadarPath.Text != "")
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(textBoxRadarPath.Text))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(textBoxRadarPath.Text);

                    btnStart.Enabled = true;
                }
            }

            if (textBoxSatellitePath.Text != "")
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(textBoxSatellitePath.Text))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(textBoxSatellitePath.Text);

                    btnStart.Enabled = true;
                }
            }

            CheckIfImagesExist();
        }
```

I'm checking if the folders in textBoxRadarPath.Text and textBoxSatellitePath.Text exist and create them if not.  Then I call the method CheckIfImagesExist();

The problem is in the folder CheckIfImagesExist(); I'm also trying to get files :
There is more code in the method but the important is the GetImagesFiles method

```
private void CheckIfImagesExist()
        {
            GetImagesFiles();
        }
```

And in GetImagesFiles

```
private void GetImagesFiles()
        {
            if (textBoxRadarPath.Text != "" || textBoxSatellitePath.Text != "")
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(textBoxRadarPath.Text))
                {
                    if (checkBoxGetImages)
                    {
                        filesRadar = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(textBoxRadarPath.Text,
                                      "*.gif", SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var t = new DirectoryInfo(textBoxRadarPath.Text).GetDirectories()
                       .OrderByDescending(d => d.LastWriteTimeUtc).First();

                        filesRadar = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(t.FullName,
                                      "*.gif", SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
                    }

                    Array.Sort(filesRadar, new MyComparer(true));
                }

                if (Directory.Exists(textBoxSatellitePath.Text))
                {
                    if (checkBoxGetImages)
                    {
                        filesSatellite = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(textBoxSatellitePath.Text,
                                                      "*.gif", SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var t = new DirectoryInfo(textBoxSatellitePath.Text).GetDirectories()
                       .OrderByDescending(d => d.LastWriteTimeUtc).First();

                        filesSatellite = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(t.FullName,
                                                 "*.gif", SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
                    }

                    Array.Sort(filesSatellite, new MyComparer(false));
                }
            }
        }
```

Here I'm trying to get images from the first child folder under textBoxRadarPath.Text and textBoxSatellitePath.Text

The problem is if the directories textBoxRadarPath.Text and textBoxSatellitePath.Text not exist so they have created but they are empty yet so I'm getting exception on the line

```
var t = new DirectoryInfo(textBoxRadarPath.Text).GetDirectories()
                           .OrderByDescending(d => d.LastWriteTimeUtc).First();
```

Because the two directories just created or they are empty.

How can I check in the constructor if the directories are empty don't call the method CheckIfImagesExist() ?

Only if there are child folders inside then call the method CheckIfImagesExist()

The exception message :

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'

On the line :

```
var t = new DirectoryInfo(textBoxRadarPath.Text).GetDirectories()
                       .OrderByDescending(d => d.LastWriteTimeUtc).First();
```

This screenshot show example of the folders structure on the hard disk.

[image: directories]

Comment: I am not following the logic in your code… if your code “creates” the folder… then why bother calling `CheckIfImagesExist();` … ?

Comment: @JohnG because if the directories are exists it will not create them.  I'm creating the directories in the constructor only if they are not exist. but if they are exist then I want to check if they have child folders inside and then to call the CheckIfImagesExist();

Comment: @JohnG I don't create the folders in the constructor in any case only if they are not exist. and in the method GetImagesFiles() I didn't check for directories : GetDirectories()
                       .OrderByDescending(d => d.LastWriteTimeUtc).First(); so everything was working fine but now when I check it if the main folders are empty it's throwing exception.

Comment: Why are you hiding the exception from us?

Comment: perhaps you should use `FirstOrDefault()` and then check if that is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FirstOrDefault when you are not sure there will be a resulting item

```
var t = new DirectoryInfo(textBoxRadarPath.Text)
        .GetDirectories()
        .OrderByDescending(d => d.LastWriteTimeUtc)
        .FirstOrDefault();  // <- this will return null if there are no entries
```

then before you start checking the files, make sure you found a directory.

```
if (t != null)
{
    filesSatellite = System.IO.Directory
            .GetFiles(t.FullName, "*.gif", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .OrderBy(x => x)
            .ToArray();
}
```